# How to add an 'echo' to terminals default output

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I'm transferring a file using:

> sudo dd if=/Directory/file_name | pv -s 11G | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m

The output while the file is transferring looks something like this:

> 398MiB 0:00:21 [23.0MiB/s] [=>                                ]  8%

I'm wanting to add in a title at the top so that the terminal output would look something like this:

> File_name transfer progress:
>   398MiB 0:00:21 [23.0MiB/s] [=>                                ]  8%

How would I go about doing this? I assume it would use the echo command somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
echo "/Directory/file_name transfer progress:"; sudo dd if=/Directory/file_name | pv -s 11G | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m
```

Will print:

```
/Directory/file_name transfer progress:
398MiB 0:00:21 [23.0MiB/s] [=> ] 8%
```

Or wrap in a script with the first argument as the file name:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 transfer progress:"
sudo dd if="$1" | pv -s 11G | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m
```